# symbolically solving nonlinear equation

Tags: solver, maxima

I can't find a way to obtain from Maxima the solution of a relatively simple equation. In fact

```
solve(x^n=a*x^m,x);
```

returns

```
[x^n=a*x^m]
```

whereas I'd like to obtain

```
x=a^(1/(n-m))
```

Any clue?

Comment: You'll have to help `solve` along the way; sorry about that. Try `log(e), logexpand = super` where `e` is your equation `x^n=a*x^m`, and then try `solve` on the result of that. I get `[x = %e^-(log(a)/(m-n))]`.

Comment: Maxima's `solve` function is relatively weak, and efforts have been made over the years to strengthen it. `solve` is probably the one function which could help users the most. For the record, I'm a Maxima developer.

Answer (score 0):

Octave can do it:

```
> pkg load symbolic
> solve(x^n==a*x^m, x)
ans = (sym)

    -1  
   ─────
   m - n
  a
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Maxima, though? Is it not possible to solve this equation _in Maxima_?

Comment: Also, Octave's `symbolic` package that this answer uses is basically a wrapper around Python's [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html). According to [`symbolic`'s README](https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/symbolic/ci/master/tree/), "Python code is generated to do the actual work", so it's not Octave that can solve this - it's SymPy